# Minimax in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, minimax

The **`fminimax`** function in MATLAB requires one of the two arguments to take a finite number of values.

However, in my setup, both arguments take values in ( two different ) compact sets of Euclidean spaces.

Specifically, in `fminimax` in MATLAB solves problems of the form

```
min_x max_i f_i(x)
```

where **`x`** can have some linear or nonlinear constraints, and **`i`** belongs to, for instance `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

However, in my problem, **`i`** takes values in some **`R^k`**-space and has ( `i` ) its own constraints. For example, `i` belongs to the unit sphere in `R^k`-space.

Of course, I can use **`fmincon`** twice to circumvent the problem. But I am looking for a more elegant solution here. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "MATLAB requires one of the two arguments to take a finite number of values" and "both arguments take values in (two different) compact sets of Euclidean spaces"? Can you give an example of some code that you have written for the problem?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your attention. I've updated my question and hopefully the question is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put up some working code for the `fmincon` approach as well? I'm still struggling to understand how this would work, especially for non-integer values of `i`.

Comment: Hi David, maybe just forget about the fmincon approach. So the question here is that is there a way in matlab to handle the case where i can have general linear or nonlinear constraints just as x.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to optimise enough to help. If you can add any extra details or some more of the formulation, I might be able to give some help, otherwise you'll have to wait for someone else to have a look.